# Tensorflow inception v3 image retrain unable to test on new .jpg image

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have successfully retrained tensorflows image_retrain inception v3 model in ubuntu 16.04 for my own image classification. The performance results are good, so I tried with `label_image.py` script to predict new image (.jpg). But I am getting error at

`predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})`

***error log***

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): NodeDef mentions attr 'dct_method' not in Op image:uint8; attr=channels:int,default=0; attr=ratio:int,default=1; attr=fancy_upscaling:bool,default=true; attr=try_recover_truncated:bool,default=false; attr=acceptable_fraction:float,default=1>; NodeDef: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"
>        [[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Kindly help me to resolve

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem myself.

As far as I can tell, there's a mismatch between the version of tensorflow you used to generate the output graph and the version you're now using to run the label_image.py script.

I spent a lot of time trying to track down the change and figuring out how to run tensorflow in the same version as I previously used to generate the graph.

In the end, I found a hacky solution that solved my problem:

After loading the graph from your file

```
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
```

Add

```
del(graph_def.node[1].attr["dct_method"])
```

This is not a great method, and if possible you should try to retrain the graph and make sure the tensorflow versions are the same.